# How do you design a trampoline from scratch? Or rather, how do you learn how to design....?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, design

I've asked similar questions here before, but I'm looking for a more 'meta' answer.

Given a niche in mechanical engineering, how do you find out what the current state of the art is in terms of design?

At present trampoline design knowledge seems to be locked up inside the companies that make trampolines.  This means that the only way to learn how to design trampolines is to go work for a company that makes trampolines.

Is this field actually just undocumented in the world at large, or am I not asking the right question in the right place?

Where is arcane bits of mech E knowledge kept?

Comment: I suggest that these things were always designed empirically, not with equations.

Comment: Agree about empirical design, but I would still expect there to be discussion somewhere about tradeoffs, best practices, and first order solutions.